# Very simple solar lithium charger (18650)

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, lipo, solar-charge-controller

I need a very simple charger for 18650 LiPos (2.6Ah.)

Since the solarcell (6V/150mA) will not be over the CC of the battery, I think only a precise 4.2V CV limiter will be sufficient.

Has anybody experience with 18650 use in lower temperatures (-10..-40°C) or a better suggestion (I need it for a scientific device in an arctic region.)

The LTspice files are here: [LTspice simple solar charger.](https://joembedded.de/xtranet/index.php?dir=./temp)

[image]

Comment: I think the "<= 4.0V" is a very good hint! The idea of using a large capacity of the cell compared to the small solar panel is run it for a longer time, even without sun.

Answer (score 5):

> I think only a precise 4.2V CV limiter will be sufficient?

No.

Continued charging at 4.2 V, at any current, will gradually plate out the active material. You must stop charging completely when the charge current falls below a suitable termination threshold.

Typically quoted thresholds are 0.05 C to 0.1 C, or 130 mA to 260 mA in your case, unless the datasheet for your cells says otherwise. This means you should stop charging as soon as the charge current falls below your maximum solar cell current of 150 mA.

Comment: Float charging sees to be ok provided the voltage is a bit less than the full-charged voltage. Say 4.0V. https://www.electronicsweekly.com/market-sectors/power/float-charging-lithium-ion-cells-2006-02/

Comment: @KevinWhite My stance was that if chargers charge to 4.2 V, then let the cell drop to 4.1 V before supplying a top-up charge, how is float charging at 4.1 V any worse? However, I've not seen manufacturer's recommendations on float charging, so have never advocated it.  Any figure (4.0, 4.1, 'a bit less') seems like a pidooma, unless we go for the NASA one of 3.92 V per cell that's used in satellites for max life, where the cells are somewhat difficult to replace. Personally, I terminate my power tool batteries at 4.1 V / cell by lying to the charger that they're LiLos.

Answer (score 0):

The solar cell you have is small relative to the lithium cell. So the current is not dangerous. You could set up a simple comparitor that disconnects the cell when the voltage hits 4.2 and depending on application reconnects at say 3.8 volt. You could use a PNP BJT instead of the NPN to improve performance at low light levels. This is not perfect but for your simple job it should be good enough.